# Changing Size and the Color of the UIComponent of Storyboard from the Inspector Menu

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I'm able to change the size of a component(on storyboard) by using the Inspector Menu of below:

[image: Inspector Menu]

But I can not change the background color of the component using Inspector Menu. It doesn't change anything When I use the menu below. Why is that?

[image: Inspector Menu for Changing The color]

Note: I Can change the color using code

Comment: Are you implying that you _can_ change its color using code? In any case, see if there's any other view that overlaps with the view.

Comment: Hi Sweeper. Yes I can Change the color by using code. And There isn't anything overlapping the view. I Do see a label on the view. Just color is not changing using inspector menu